# Playitslowly bug

Tags: sound

I love the audio player playitslowly for its ability to change pitch and play speed. However, it sometimes runs improperly ; after 10-15 seconds of playing a song, the file is still being read but no sound is outputted. This bug has been present for a long time (since I have been using 12.04).

So I guess this is a known bug since it's been around for so long, but I'll admit I don't know where to check if it's known or how to "make it" known. Either way, I'd like an alternative to this audio player : does anyone know of another Ubuntu-accessible audio player that can do the pitch and play speed modification just like playitslowly can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To report the bug, feel free to leave a comment on the Playitslowly website at https://29a.ch/playitslowly , or better yet, email the author Jonas Wagner directly -- you'll find his email address on the "About" page of that website.

He has also created a web-based player with similar features called **TimeStretch**: https://29a.ch/timestretch/

The Linux audio editor **Audacity** has features to adjust pitch and playback speed of an audio file, but it may not be as simple and easy to use as Playitslowly or TimeStretch.

Comment: I did e-mail him and I like the online player TimeStretch ; it suffices my needs. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad TimeStretch is working for you! It appears that running playitslowly with `gksu playitslowly` in a temrinal window might fix the audio issue, according to one of the author's comments on his website. You may (possibly) need to install the gksu package first by running `sudo apt install gksu` in a terminal. Of course, if TimeStretch meets your needs, this might not matter anymore!

Comment: It would matter still, since it would improve the app for the future.  The `gksu` trick didn't fix my issue, I experienced it after running playitslowly using it.